# Como fazer um "select like" a um resultado de uma subquery

Tags: sql, servidor

Necessito de fazer um `select` em `sql server 2014` ao resultado de uma subquery, exemplo:

`select * from tabela2 where codigo like ("1;3;4","3","1;2;5")`

Onde (`"1;3;4","3","1;2;5"`) é o resultado da subquery (`select * from tabela1`)
de forma a obter o seguinte resultado:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um join:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tabela2 t
INNER JOIN (SELECT codigo
            FROM tabela1
            GROUP BY codigo) E
    ON t.codigo LIKE '%' || E.codigo|| '%'
```